# Error in Pspice: Circuit too large when using 74LS192

Tags: simulation, error

I have tried using 74LS192 in my Pspice simulation but it keeps on making an error page saying that the circuit is too large. I have tried just using only the 74LS192 to see if the error would pop up and it did. I'm a student and I am using Pspice LITE which allows only up to 36 transistors at a time. Do I have to use a different transistor or is there another way to use the current one? [image]
[image]

Comment: You need to ask a question because all you've done is state a problem. However, it seems like you have no options other than to choose a free (and component unlimited) simulation package like micro-cap.

Comment: Oh, sorry that was my mistake. I guess that is actually the only possible way... Thank you for the advice.